# Unbiased estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

$X$ and $Y$ are two independent discrete random variable. A quantity is defined as $\;V=P\big[X>Y|X\ne Y\big]$. Kindly help me in finding unbiased estimator for $V$.

I am new in this field and currently having no clue on how to find such things. If you can provide a starting point that will also help. Thank you.

Comment: What information are you going to use to find this estimator? Such as a sample of $X$ and $Y$? Or their distributions?

Comment: Their distribution. E.g, X~Bin(n,p), Y~Geom(a)